# How to wakeup a Sip Phone at iPhone? I cannot call to it till it's not running

Tags: android, iphone, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I have a Freeswitch+FusionPBX server.

I have 2 numbers and devices

- 100@192.168.0.100 at Android (CsipSimple). The software has an option to stay running.
- 101@192.168.0.100 at iPhone (MitraPhone).

**How it works**

- Since Android app is always running, I can always make a call from iPhone to Android.
- Since the iPhone app is not running in the background, I can never call to iPhone except when MitraPhone is open.

**Question**

How to use SipPhones as expected at iPhone? So I can call to iPhone any time.

**Suggestion**

Since there should be some push to wakeup the iPhone app, maybe there is some SipPhone for both Android and iPhone, which can push each other on call?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no softphone that does what you want. But basic pieces are available.

For VoIP pushes, Apple released a specific API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit

Apple also released CallKit to seamlessly integrate your VoIP service to general calling UI.

Someone tried to persuade freeswitch core developers to build the needed server-side module, with no luck:
https://freeswitch.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/FS-4347/FS-4347.html

These are what came up with a little bit of googleing.

Comment: I added a FreeSwitch dialplan to send a push to Apple. It works with a custom soft phone developed specially to get the push, but not in general case. 

In fact at Apple it's currently not possible to use SIPhones, though there is a number of soft phones in the apple store. This makes the softphones useless. I'm cofused and frustrated.